# Syntax error - Logical if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, logical-operators

I`m just using a If statement with the logical operator. I dont know why it is showing sytax error.

```
var divWidth = $("#columnwraper").width(); //getting the width of the div   
$("#right-button").click(function() {
    if (cursor != totalWidth && totalWidth !< divWidth) {
        $box2.animate({
            marginLeft : "-=300"
        }, "fast");

        cursor += 100;
    }
    // console.log(colwidth.width());
});
```

It`s showing that

> [15:18:24.050] SyntaxError: missing ) after condition.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What is `!<` operator? Why you don't use `>=` instead?

Comment: Note that `!=` is *one* operator. It is not a combination of `!` and `==`. You cannot simply combine `!` with other operators (i.e. `!<` is invalid).

Comment: @FelixKling Noted felix. Thank you.

Comment: No idea why this is being voted to close - this question is fine and has a valid accepted answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Put it this way:

```
if (cursor != totalWidth && !(totalWidth < divWidth))
```

`!<` is not an [operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators).

Answer (score 2):

Error in `totalWidth !< divWidth`

Should be `totalWidth < divWidth` **or** `totalWidth >= divWidth`

Comment: Or `>=`. I think the `!` is not just a typo.

Answer (score 1):

Always put logical operators in inner brackets for operations like: `(totalWidth < divWidth)`

And `!<` is not an operator.
You should use this:

```
 if ((cursor != totalWidth) && !(totalWidth < divWidth)) {... }
```